# currentDevice.name and iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8, ios10

I'm working on an Obective-C app with XCode 8.0 (beta build *8S128d*) and iOS 10.0 (beta build *14A5297c*) and I stumbled upon a weird issue.

Whenever I call `[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]`, the app crashes, the process stops in XCode, and the only log I get in the console is

`[access] <private>`

It doesn't work either when using an ipa compiled with XCode 7, so I guess the problem comes from iOS 10.

Did anyone else get the same behavior? Is there any solution?

Thanks!